# Update notification content using @capacitor/local-notifications (5.0.6) plugin

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, mobile-application, ionic7

I'm developing a workout application with Ionic 7 (ReactTS) using Capacitor.
I would like to display a notification with the remaining rest time before the next set to the user.
The displayed remaining rest time should be updated every second.

What I've tried:

- LocalNotifications.schedule with the same ID but it's just canceling the notification and creating a new one. The sound and visual effects are triggered again.
- LocalNotifications.removeAllDeliveredNotifications and then LocalNotifications.schedule with the same ID but it's just canceling the notification and creating a new one. The sound and visual effects are triggered again.

If anyone knows of a plugin or has a solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my component "CountDown.tsx" :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
// Assets
import BoxingBellSound from '../../assets/sounds/boxingBell.mp3';
// Components
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from 'react-countdown-circle-timer';
// Libraries
import {
  LocalNotifications,
  LocalNotificationSchema,
} from '@capacitor/local-notifications';
import { App, AppState } from '@capacitor/app';
// Styles
import './CountDown.css';

interface Props {
  value: number;
  title: string;
}

const CountDown: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, value }) => {
  let remainingTime: number = value;

  const sendNotification = async () => {
    const notification: LocalNotificationSchema = {
      id: 1,
      title,
      body: `${remainingTime}`,
      smallIcon: 'res://icon.png',
    };

    await LocalNotifications.schedule({
      notifications: [notification],
    });
  };

  const renderChildren = (remainingTime: number) => {
    const minutes: number = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60);
    const seconds: number = remainingTime % 60;
    const formattedMinutes: string =
      minutes >= 10 ? minutes.toString() : `0${minutes}`;
    const formattedSeconds: string =
      seconds >= 10 ? seconds.toString() : `0${seconds}`;
    return `${formattedMinutes}:${formattedSeconds}`;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (remainingTime > 0) {
        remainingTime -= 1;
        sendNotification();
      } else {
        new Audio(BoxingBellSound).play();
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <CountdownCircleTimer
      isPlaying
      duration={value}
      colors={['#004777', '#F7B801', '#A30000', '#A30000']}
      colorsTime={[7, 5, 2, 0]}
      size={80}
    >
      {({ remainingTime }) => renderChildren(remainingTime)}
    </CountdownCircleTimer>
  );
};

export default CountDown;
```